# validate with "has_many :through"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, orm, associations

I have `validate :my_validate` in my User model, but `my_validate` is never called if "has_may :through" attribute is changed. Is it right behavior?

My code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base

  has_many :roles, :through => :user_roles

  validate :my_validate
  def my_validate
    raise 123
  end
```

This throws exception:

```
User.find(1).name = 'new_name'
```

This works:

```
User.find(1).roles = []
```

I understand that user table is not updating so rails think validating is not necessary, but it looks really weird.

Answer (score 0):

```
User.find(1).name = 'new_name'
```

It is throwing exception because you want to assign name with some value and try to saving value to users table, In validate methods "my_validate" you are raising some error, means it will throw an error if you want to save any value.

```
User.find(1).roles = []
```

But in second methods you are assign some value to roles table not in
 users table. That wise it is not throwing any error.

Comment: "I understand that user table is not updating so rails think validating is not necessary, but it looks really weird."

Comment: I believe validation is not about "tables", it should be about "models". "roles" and "name" are both attributes, they should behave equally despite of their inner representation.

Comment: I mean that when you use save methods in user model it try to save data in your table, example user = User.find(1).name = 'new_name' and user.save that time it will try to store data in users table.